# DJango [Errno 10013] When Performing Post

Tags: python, django, rest

I'm trying to perform a POST message to another server during an REST API method in DJango.  I'm using the django rest framework package,  When I attempt the POST I get an [Errno 10013] error.

```
class Activate(APIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.BasicAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        registration = Registration.objects.get(activateKey=request.GET.get('activateKey','unset'));
        if registration is None:
            return Response("not found", status = 404);
        else:
            url = django_settings.get('service_url') + '/user/' + registration.Id;
            params = urllib.urlencode({'activateKey': registration.activateKey,});
            response = urllib2.urlopen(url, params).read();
            return Response(response.getcode());
```

From what I've read this usually happens when listening on a port but I'm posting so not sure what's going wrong.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My URL was incorrect, so the error message was a bit of a red herring.  I had left my local URL in which wasn't accessible from the server.